# I am trying to connect to a particular wifi SSID and create a auto-connect function to that particular SSID eventhough when its priority is low

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to connect to a particular WiFi SSID and create an auto-connect function to that particular SSID eventhough when its priority is low.

I should get notified when the user gets into my WiFi range of that particular wifi SSID.
Thanks in advance.